# I want to extract a query parameter from a database column in our postgresql database using postgresql but am having no success

Tags: postgresql, query-string

I am trying to grab the query parameters using postgresql but having issues because the parameters are not always in the same order. I have a table that looks like the below:

```
username |             context_page
________________________________________________
John     |?promo=summer21&campaign=presidentsDay
Sam      |?campaign=july4th&promo=summer21
Chris    |?promo=spring&campaign=baseball
```

I have tried the below with no success:

```
SELECT split_part(substring(conversion.context_page from '[?&]promo=[^&]+'), '=', 2),
context_page_search 
FROM conversion;
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if You have a fixed list of query parameters (promo and campaign) try this:

```
SELECT username, 
       (REGEXP_MATCH(context_page, '[?&]promo=([^&]+)'))[1] AS promo, 
       (REGEXP_MATCH(context_page, '[?&]campaign=([^&]+)'))[1] AS campaign
FROM conversion;
```

you'll get params in separate columns

```
username    promo       campaign
-------------------------------------
John        summer21    presidentsDay
Sam         summer21    july4th
Chris       spring      baseball
```